# Change direction for mobiles in HTML Tables

Tags: html, css

i have this table , need for mobiles change their directions (td with image on top and td with text on bottom) without using flex and order

```html
<table width="100%" align="left"
  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
  role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" valign="top" align="left">
            <span style="color: #8F8F89;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </span>
        </td>
        <td width="20%" align="center"
          valign="top" class="cell">
            <table width="100%"
              border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
              role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i tried to add for main table direction:rtl, but it doesnt work properly

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question - it showed me `role` which I'd never used before. To make your code easier to debug, may I suggest pushing the common `table` attributes out to a stylesheet and removing the redundant(?) width declaration?

Comment: [ADVICE]: Besides your problem, DO NOT use attributes or inline CSS to style any element , at least when your asking question.

Comment: Is your data actually tabular? The layout looks a bit “old fashioned” with out of date attributes. Could you describe why this set up is used rather than flex or grid?

Comment: Does [this article](https://www.litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design) help?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use tables for layout (presentation). Use a grid instead.

When running this snippet, to see the responsive behaviour, use the **full page** link and adjust the width of your browser window.

```css
.g1 {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .g1 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.g1>*:first-child {
  color: #8F8F89;
}

.g1>*:last-child {
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="g1">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

Comment: need to use tables , because doing email letters

Comment: Okay, so please edit your question to include that information.